# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, array

estoy leyendo un array de arrays con python pero en una de las llaves tiene una forma distinta. ¿como la condiciono para que la ignore?.

ej: el array

```
data = (results: {{tmp:{'0':'casa','1':'perro'}},
{tmp:{'0':'bola','1':'gato'}},
{tmp:['0','casa','perro']})
```

el código

```
for line in data['results']:
         print(line['tmp'][1])
```

estoy buscando que me imprima los valores de la llave '1'
lo cual genera un error por la tercera linea la cual tiene forma diferente, agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Revisa ese "array" porque está incongruente. Tiene 3 llaves abiertas sin cierre. Por otro lado, Python interpretará `results` y `tmp` como variables y las intentará evaluar, provocando error si no están definidas. Un índice tipo cadena debe ser `'result'` y `'tmp'`.

Comment: gracia, disculpa es un ejemplo resumido para lo que intento decir, ok quizas tengo que ser mas especifico pero en realidad el "array" que estoy leyendo viene asi el problema son los corchetes de algunas lineas como se muestra en el ejemplo

Comment: Efectivamente tu fallo es en cómo pones el "array", que por cierto NO es un array. Tienes una biblioteca específica de arrays en python llamada literalmente array. Estas trabajando con diccionarios, cada "key" tiene su "value" y tu manera de presentarlo en la variable es incorrecta. Un saludo

Comment: repito, es un ejemplo de como esta armado lo que estoy leyendo, mi inconveniente es que una de las key (tmp) viene conectada al value diferente y me esta generando un error, repito es un ejemplo de el verdadero codigo

Comment: Tu ejemplo tiene una sintaxis que Python no acepta. Por ejemplo asignas a result un valor dentro de una tupla, lo que tira un sintax error. Si no corriges el "array" que pasaste, no podremos ayudarte. Lo siento.

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar, aprendi varios conceptos no gracias a los comentarios de
**MI EJEMPLO**

No es un array como yo pensaba es una biblioteca y esta biblioteca tiene listas una de las listas en la biblioteca no tiene llaves así que la condición es simple

```
for line in data['results']:
      if '1' in line:
       print(line['tmp'][1])
```

Quiere decir que si existe la llave '1' en la lista de la biblioteca, imprima solo esos valores

Comment: Perdón, solo intento ayudar, no quería ofender. Para mi visión pythonesca, eso era una especie de diccionario. Quizá yo también me equivoqué al pensar eso. Aun asi, me alegro de que lo hayas podido resolver!

Comment: El problema es burlarse de la ignorancia, siendo un espacio para aprender si me hubiera dicho desde el principio que era un diccionario o una lista hubiera sido mas facil el proceso, pero como dije gracias por su tiempo y que pena por mi ignorancia

Comment: No nos burlábamos de tu ignorancia, perdón si así pareció. Solo intentábamos avisar que la sintaxis de tu diccionario no era correcta y pedíamos que lo corrigieras para poderte ayudar. Además, @esteban te lo dijo.